Hibernate forces foreign key to be non-null
I want a Product to have an optional ProductType.
But during schema generation, Hibernate for some reason ignores my definition and creates a non-nullable column for a foreign-key.
We are using Hibernate for schema management and SQL Server 16.
This is what Hibernate logs out during schema creation:
Hibernate: drop table if exists my_product
Hibernate: drop table if exists my_producttype
create table my_product (id uniqueidentifier not null, name varchar(255) not null, typeId uniqueidentifier not null, primary key (id))
create table my_producttype (id uniqueidentifier not null, name varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))
alter table pg_product add constraint FK123456789 foreign key (typeId) references my_producttype

This is the schema as defined in Java:
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_product")
public class Product extends CoreModel<Product> {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "typeId", nullable = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    @org.springframework.lang.Nullable
    private ProductType productType;
}

and this abstract model class
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class CoreModel<T extends CoreModel<T>> {

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    @Column(updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Id
    private UUID id;
}

and finally the referenced entity
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_producttype")
public class ProductType extends CoreModel<ProductType> {


    @NotNull
    private String name;
}

the relevant application.yml
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
  jpa:
    database: sql_server
    open-in-view: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
      naming:
        implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
        jdbc:
          time_zone: UTC

What I tried:

using a different nullable annotation (from Spring/Java/Jakarta)
checking that I setup the @ManyToOne correctly (see Hibernate not respecting nullable=true in @JoinColumn annotation)

System information

Spring 3.3.0
Hibernate 6.5.2
MS SQL Server 16.00.4125
mssql-jdbc 12.6.1


@JohnWilliams a foreign key can be perfectly null, SQL is not disallowing it (a reference can be optional). So you don't need to have dummy relations in your database.

Found the culprit, and I have to apologize, since you couldn't have figured it out.
The property productType is private and therefore has getters and setters, which I omitted. Crucially, during the refactor, I forgot to remove the @NotNull annotation there - and today I learned, that Spring/Hibernate introspects these as well during Schema generation, not just the field annotations.
Fix was to change from this:
    public @NotNull ProductType getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }

    public void setProductType(@NotNull ProductType productType) {
        this.productType = productType;
    }

to this
    public ProductType getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }

    public void setProductType(ProductType productType) {
        this.productType = productType;
    }

Sorry about that, but thanks for being my rubber-duck
